# Is it possible to generate css conditionally using css pre processor?

Tags: css, sass, less, modernizr

When I use modernizr, it'll add `rgba` or `no-rgba` class in my `html` tag. I'm trying to generate mixins using `LESS`. For example:

```
.background-content{
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

header{
  .background-content;
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is if `rgba` exist then:

```
.background-content{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

But if `no-rgba` exist then I want it to be like this:

```
.background-content{
  background: #000;
}
```

My question is, is it possible to generate mixins using condition? Is it possible when I do **`.background-content` inside `header`**, it'll give different background color depending on which class exists? If `LESS` can't do it, can `SASS` do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible for a pre-processor to know anything about your HTML or how it is being read by the browser. If I understand right, however, you can get what you need (and more) with Sass:

```
@mixin background-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  .no-rgba & { background: #000; }
}

header {
  @include background-content;
}
```

You can make that even more flexible by taking arguments:

```
@mixin background-content($rgba, $no-rgba: rgba($rgba,1)) {
  background: $rgba;
  .no-rgba & { background: $no-rgba; }
}

header {
  @include background-content(rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

The conditions are inside the mixin, rather than needing to be hard-coded each time.

Comment: Yah now I can see where my question was flawed. So it's not possible then. I forgot that CSS tree is separate from DOM tree.

Comment: Well, it's also the nature of *pre*-processing. The logic is all resolved before the code reaches a browser. There is work being done to move ideas from Sass & Less into CSS (see variables, calc, and talk of integrated modernizr-style support checking). Putting the logic directly into the browser will change everything, exactly in the ways you are looking for.